# Why I can't record first and last records on an array to Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, nosql, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to register 20 users and create a document on my collection for each of them on Firebase Firestore. My program successfully registers 20 users but fails when creating documents for them. 18, 19 documents created each time but it almost always skip to create a document for the first member and the last member of my array. StudentCreator is just a file that has  a parent array, student array with 20 items.
Here is an array from studentCreator.java

`public static String parent_names[]={
            "Ahmet Lola",
            "Hüseyin Kutlutürk",
            "Ümit Uğrak",
            "Veysel Karani",
            "Serkan Gotar",
            "Dündar Zalim",
            "Kadir Berkay",
            "Uğur Özdemir",
            "Bünyamin Akgün",
            "Kaptan Price",
            "Selim Tekiner",
            "Gökçe Yılan",
            "Talip Özkan",
            "Abdurrahman Tarikçi",
            "Selim Kirlier",
            "Hasan Can Doğan",
            "Erdem Gökşen",
            "Fatoş Ünal",
            "Nurgül Birtek",
            "Yuan Hui"};`

Here the main code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Intent LoginActivity = new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
    final Intent TeacherActivity = new Intent(this,TeacherActivity.class);
    final Intent ParentActivity = new Intent(this,ParentActivity.class);
    final Intent ManagerActivity = new Intent(this,ManagerActivity.class);


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final String username = StudentCreator.parent_names[i].replaceAll(" ", "") + StudentCreator.student_numbers[i];
        final String email = username + "@onurmail.com";
        final String password = "123456";

        final String student_name = StudentCreator.student_names[i];
        final String parent_name = StudentCreator.parent_names[i];
        //Registration is successul here.
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("User Registered", "createUserWithEmail:success");

                            final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            final String user_id = user.getUid();
                            //I get valid userId's for 20 users.
                            //CREATE STUDENT OBJECT AND FIREBASE INSTANCES
                            final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

                            final Map<String, Object> student = new HashMap<>();
                            student.put("student_name", student_name);
                            student.put("parent_name", parent_name);
                            //My first element of array comes here and prints its parent name and student name perfectly but cant see anything about it on database.
                            //PUT STUDENT TO THE DB
                            db.collection("TED_Ankara")
                                    .document(parent_name)
                                    .set(student)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User  inserted sucessfully: "+parent_name,
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }
                                            else {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User cannot be inserted: "+parent_name,
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }

                                        }
                                    });

                            //PUT STUDENT TO THE DB



                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                });

    }
  }
}
```

Please help. I am suspicious about addOnCompleteListener and firebaseAuth's usage. But i am not sure really. Thanks for any help.

Edit: Adding the first member without the for loop works without any problem. So i guess the problem is about the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase SDK only can have a single active user. Since you're running over the array in a so-called tight loop, I suspect that you may be creating a next user, before the code has started writing the document for the previous user. To verify whether this is indeed the problem, can you try to see if this fixes it?

Add a function to create the users

```
void createNextUser(List<String> student_names, List<String> student_numbers, List<String> parent_names) {
  if (student_names.size() > 0 && student_numbers.size() > 0 && parent_names.size() > 0) {
    final String student_name = student_names.remove(0);
    final String student_number = student_numbers.remove(0);
    final String parent_name = parent_names.remove(0);
    final String username = parent_name.replaceAll(" ", "") + student_number;
    final String email = username + "@onurmail.com";
    final String password = "123456";


    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d("User Registered", "createUserWithEmail:success");

                    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    final String user_id = user.getUid();
                    //I get valid userId's for 20 users.
                    //CREATE STUDENT OBJECT AND FIREBASE INSTANCES
                    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

                    final Map<String, Object> student = new HashMap<>();
                    student.put("student_name", student_name);
                    student.put("parent_name", parent_name);
                    //My first element of array comes here and prints its parent name and student name perfectly but cant see anything about it on database.
                    //PUT STUDENT TO THE DB
                    db.collection("TED_Ankara")
                            .document(parent_name)
                            .set(student)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User  inserted sucessfully: "+parent_name,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User cannot be inserted: "+parent_name,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    // Now that we're done with this user, move on to the next one
                                    createNextUser(student_names, student_number, parent_names);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        });    
  }
}
```

The big difference in this code is that it only starts creating the next user, once it's done creating the previous user and its document. It does this by:

1. removing the current student from the list when it starts

   ```
   final String student_name = student_names.remove(0);
   final String student_number = student_numbers.remove(0);
   final String parent_name = parent_names.remove(0);
   ```
2. calling itself after writing the document

   ```
   // Now that we're done with this user, move on to the next one
   createNextUser(student_names, student_number, parent_names);
   ```

Now all that is left to do is kicking off the process in your `onCreate` with:

```
createNextUser(Arrays.asList(StudentCreator.student_names), Arrays.asList(StudentCreator.student_numbers), Arrays.asList(StudentCreator.parent_names));
```

---

Note: creating accounts for other users is an administrative action, and as such should typically not be performed from an Android client. I highly recommend checking out the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), which has better support for such operations. It must be used in a trusted environment, so not in an Android app, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am really happy to get an answer from a real professional. As far as i understand it is a bad attitude to use a loop to create some numbers of documents and i will start using the Admin SDK tonight.I just wanna ask that, shouldn't my program stop at the addOnCompleteListener, when creating a document for that user? In my understanding it should wait there no matter what. Isn't that the case? Is it just continuing the loop and skipping the listeners?

Comment: The program doesn't stop. The creation of the user and of the document happen asynchronously, and your `onComplete` gets called once they complete. But your loop is not blocked, so it kicks of all 20 straight away. My code makes it so that they go in sequence: one after the other.